# Covariance in delegate, any example?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, covariance, contravariance

I'm reading [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx), the contravariance example (keyboard and mouse event) is great and useful, while the covariance example (Mammal and Dog) doesn't look so.

The keyboard and mouse event is great since you can use 1 handler for multiple cases; but I can't think of the advantages of assigning a handler that returns a more derived type to a handler returning base type, not to mention it looks like less common to have a delegate which cares about return type?

Could someone please provide a more practical example of covariance in delegate?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "real world" example where I implement a service locator. I want to make a class where I can register "factory" delegates that know how to produce instances of some type, then resolve instances of some type later on. Here is what that looks like:

```
interface ISomeService { ... }
class SomeService : ISomeService { ... }

class IocContainer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _factories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();

    public void Register<T>(Func<T> factory)
        where T: class 
    {
        _factories[typeof(T)] = factory;
    }

    // Note: this is C#6, refactor if not using VS2015
    public T Resolve<T>() => (T)_factories[typeof(T)]();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new IocContainer();
        container.Register<ISomeService>(() => new SomeService());

        // ...

        var service = container.Resolve<ISomeService>();
    }
}
```

Now, where I'm doing `container.Register<ISomeService>(() => new SomeService())`, the covariance of `Func` delegates comes into play on two levels:

1. I can pass in a `Func<SomeService>` and it is assignable where a `Func<ISomeService>` is expected with no problems, because a `SomeService` is a `ISomeService`
2. Inside the `Register` method, a `Func<T>` can be assigned where a `Func<object>` is expected with no problems, because any reference type is an `object`

If a `Func<SomeService>` wasn't assignable to a `Func<ISomeService>`, or `Func<ISomeService>` wasn't assignable to a `Func<object>` (via covariance), this example wouldn't work.

Comment: Is the same also possible with contravariance? E.g. an Action per type? I couldnt get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, it is not common an event to return with a value, it's kinda convention (actually it is more than convention: see extra reading #2). However delegates are not only for events, basically they are the .NET version of the near half century old C style "pointer to a function" (C terminology).

To leave the mystery left on events and delegates and listeners (java) in control flow concept they are just simple *callbacks*, so it is completely reasonable if they have return value.

So from this *callback* point of view:
Say I would like to process animals. I would like to use a function pointer (I mean: delegate or lambda) to do a *part* of this processing. Lets call it FeedAnimal. I would like to have an other skeleton method which calls this feed method, lets call it CareAnimal. I would like to *plugin* the feed algorithm to the care algorithm *with* run time variable mode, so the Care will have a delegate parameter: feed. After feeding the feed method returns an animal.

Now the point: The feed will have different implementations for Dog and Cat, one returns with Dog and the other returns with Cat.... and the Care() method accepts a delegate parameter which returns with Animal.

[Extra reading #1]: This kind of polymorphic implementation is the *not* OOP polymorphism implementaion. In OOP you can achieve similar with virtual method overloads.

[Extra reading #2]: The *really* disturbing thing about delegates (and events) that they are *multicast* delegates I mean one single delegate (which is a multicast delegate by default) can contain *many* method entry point. When it is invoked then all contained methods invoked in a cycle in *not* *specified* *order*. However there will be *one* return value in case the signature is not void. Of course this is confusing, so we safely say: If we use the multicast feature of delegates (or events) then it makes no sense other signature than void return.
Events are typically multicast, this comes from the Publisher/Subscriber DP metaphore: Many subscriber (handler) can subscribe (+=) to the publishers publication *without* knowing anything about each other.

Comment: I don't understand what events have to do with this

Comment: @Asad they don't, but the querent seemed to think they do.

Comment: @Asad: It would be nice if events (what are higher level metaphores) were not mixed with delegates and more generally with callback control flow, but unfortunately they mixed. Also, the referred article (and generally MSDN always talks about only events (bad).

Comment: @g.pickardou Thanks for replying. But I got a thought, the `Feed` method looks more like to have a signature of `void Feed(Animal a)` than `Animal Feed()`, since the animal is "to be fed", anyway? So the Feed example is still more like a contravariance example to me...I think the Factory example (by Asad) is more practical, although it is just a typical example.

Comment: @g.pickardou By the wat, extra point 2 is a great view. So I'll say that covariance is only useful for callback (not multicast), for now.

Comment: @MarsonMao: You are right about Feed return value. Then let's say Feed returns with the quantity of successful feed. This is a very common sense programming example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look at the declaration of the [`Func<T, TResult>` Delegate.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(
    T arg
)
```

You can see that the type of the input parameter is contravariant but the type of the result or return value is covariant.

The familiar Linq extension `Select`, has [an overload that accepts this delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx).

Additionally, note that the return type of `Select` is `IEnumerable<T>`,
that is a covariant interface, i.e.

```
public IEnumerable<out T>
{
    \\ ...
}
```

Now consider the types,

```
abstract class Mammal
{
}
```

and

```
class Dog : Mammal
{
}
```

I can declare an instance of the delegate.

```
var doItToMammals = new Func<Mammal, Mammal>(mammal => mammal);
```

I can pass this delegate to `Select` without variance.

```
IEnumerable<Mammal> mammals = new List<Mammal>().Select(doItToMammals);
```

Now, because the input of the function is contravariant, I can do

```
IEnumerable<Mammal> mammals = new List<Dog>().Select(doItToMammals);
```

**Now here's the point**, because the result is covariant, I can do

```
IEnumerable<Dogs> dogs = new List<Dog>().Select<Dog, Dog>(doItToMammals);
```